# Display text from throwable (Java)

Tags: java, debugging, variables

So I am running the debugger and came across a variable 'e' which I think is error. But within that variable e is a variable "detailMessage". What is the code to get that string displayed?

I would like something along these lines
System.out.println("The error is " + e.detailMessage );

e is e  MySQLSyntaxErrorException  (id=67)

Where e.detailMessage is the string.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is

```
e.getMessage();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()

Answer (score 1):

From the Java 7 API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) the method you want is `getMessage()`.

```
System.out.println("The error is " + e.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to show exceptions is by using a `Logger`, but for simplicity's sake, you should probably use `e.printStackTrace()`, this shows you the error as well as the stack where it occured. If you really want just the message (which in itself is not usually very useful) use `getMessage()`

```
try{
 // ... do something ...
} catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It is for a database so I don't want the user seeing the stack, just the message. Thanks though, I got it working with getMessage

Comment: Users probably won't see the console ;). That is exactly what loggers are for:- you write stack traces to a file (an not the console) allowing you to more easily find problems if (read **when**) they happen.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is `getMessage`.

In code:

```
System.out.println("The error is " + e.getMessage());
```